# Thredded Ruby Gem - How To Config Email of Thredded Initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, forum, rails-engines

I'm a fresh learner in RoR.

Recently, I've been giving a try to have a forum added in my Rails site.
I am suggested to try [Thredded](https://github.com/thredded/thredded).

It has no wiki for setting email yet, that lead me to post a question here.
There are only some comments on the initializer about setting up email, but not much clear enough for me to implement, and I always get 500 error since my configuration is not right.

I appreciate for any answers, ideas, or clarification.
Thanks,

Comment: please show your code attempt and show the error.

Comment: Within your development.log you should see some more information about the error.

Comment: My thredded config:

`Thredded.email_from = 'myemail@gmail.com'`

`Thredded.email_incoming_host = 'localhost:3000'`

`Thredded.email_reply_to = -> postable { "#{postable.hash_id}@#{Thredded.email_incoming_host}" }`

Error:

`Net::SMTPFatalError (554 Transaction failed: Domain contains illegal character
)`

This is what I understand from the error.
Is my config wrong?